# Return 0 counts in GROUP BY with multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL script that the returns the count of new users per week by city. The problem is it omits any city that doesn't have users in a week. I need it to return 0 when there were no users that week.

```
select 
  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS([u.created_at:pst]) - MOD(TO_DAYS([u.created_at:pst]) -1, 7)) as week,
  a.city,
  count(u.id) as this_week_signups_to_date
from users u
left join addresses a on a.user_id = u.id
group by 
  week, city
order by 
  week DESC
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Should that be left join instead of felt join?

Comment: Good catch, fixed now

Comment: So wouldn't you want to read from Addresses and left join to users if you want it to return all cities and then user count including nulls? You are currently left joining but the left table is users.

Comment: You can't actually select data that isn't there. Recommend using your application code to detect these gaps when displaying and to fill out the empty row. Btw there is a [WEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function.

Comment: BTW what MySQL version? Sometimes there's version dependent things that can help

Comment: Unfortunately this is going straight from a db to a reporting tool, so there is no application code. Also unfortunately its MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the smoothest solution, but you could use a cross join operation like this:

```
select week,
        case when joined.city = all_cities.city then this_week_signups_to_date else 0 end 
         as this_week_signups_to_date,
        all_cities.city
from
    (select 
           week([u.created_at:pst]) as week, --you could use week() in mysql or datepart() in t-sql
           a.city,
           count(u.id) as this_week_signups_to_date
     from users u
     left join addresses a on a.user_id = u.id --left/right join depends on your needs
     group by week, city) joined
cross join 
    (select distinct city from addresses) all_cities
order by week desc
```